# store date objects to array

Tags: javascript, date, for-loop

I have two dates and want to save the days in between (plus start and end date) in an array

```
    var date1 = new Date("Sep 23, 2013 12:00:00"); // Monday
    var date2 = new Date("Sep 26, 2013 12:00:00"); // Thursday

    var alldates = [];

    for (var i=0; date1 <= date2; date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1), i++) {
        alldates.push(date1);
        }

    alert(alldates.join('\n'));
```

With this code `alert(alldates.join('\n'));` shows the following

```
    Fri Sep 27 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
    Fri Sep 27 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
    Fri Sep 27 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
    Fri Sep 27 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
```

I am new to Javascript and want to get further understanding, so thank you for any explanation why the `alert` does not show

```
    Mon Sep 23 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
    Tue Sep 24 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
    Wed Sep 25 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
    Thu Sep 26 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you have is that you push references to the `date1` object. When you change the date on it in your loop, you update the object, but all references still point to the same object.

You need to either push a text representation of your date, or a copy of your `date1` object

```
for (var i=0; date1 <= date2; date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1), i++) {
    alldates.push(new Date(date1));
    }

alert(alldates.join('\n'));
```

As suggested, with a while loop

```
while( date1 <= date2 ) {
  alldates.push(new Date(date1));
  date1.setDate( date1.getDate() +1 );
}
```

Comment: `new Date(date1)` is enough, no need to `.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Your array is storing the references for the single date object and everytime when setDate is called each of them are getting updated with new date value.

So it will be better to push the new date object in array like this,

```
var date1 = new Date("Sep 23, 2013 12:00:00"); // Monday
var date2 = new Date("Sep 26, 2013 12:00:00"); // Thursday

var alldates = [];
// pushing first date
alldates.push(new Date(date1.setDate(date1.getDate())));

for (var i=0; date1 <= date2; i++) {

    alldates.push(new Date(date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1)));
}

alert(alldates.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To echo the other answers, the issue is that the element being pushed to the array isn't a value which stays the same - it refers to a `Date` object which changes in the loop, so all references to `date1` stored in `alldates` are set to the final value of `date1`.

The accepted answer does the job, but it also mutates the value of `date1`. The OP set up the code with this side effect, which suggests that this isn't a problem for their use case. But if you'd prefer to not mutate `date1`, here's an alternative ES6-flavored, side effect-free approach:

```js
const date1 = new Date("Sep 23, 2013 12:00:00"); // Monday
const date2 = new Date("Sep 26, 2013 12:00:00"); // Thursday
const msPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 86400000
const inclusiveDateLength = (date2 - date1) / msPerDay + 1; // 4

const allDates = Array.from(Array(inclusiveDateLength), (_, i) => {
  const newDate = new Date(date1);
  newDate.setDate(date1.getDate() + i);

  return newDate;
});

console.log(allDates.join("\n"));
```

**Explanation**: We create an array, fill it new [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)s, and increment the day of the month of each of those Dates with [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate). A cool feature of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is that it accepts a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function as its second argument. We leverage the index value (`i`) in the `map` function to increment the day of the month of each date - note that this also works for wrap-arounds, such as `Sep 29` to `Oct 02`.

When the [Temporal API](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs) becomes available, it will probably offer a better solution to this problem.